# Convex Hexagon divided into 7 Congruent Triangles

Tags: geometry, polygons

So the motivation for this problem comes from the Asian Pacific Math Olympiad 1990, problem 5:

*Show that for every integer n ≥ 6, there exists a convex hexagon which can be dissected into exactly n congruent triangles*

The interesting part is trying to find a tiling of a convex hexagon into 7 congruent triangles, such as the one below

[image: example]

There are some immediate variations of this one by rearranging some triangles, but I'm curious if there are other tilings with different types of triangles, i.e. non congruent to the one used here.

Thanks

Edit: Some resources
[Solutions by Canadian Problems Committee](https://www.apmo-official.org/static/solutions/apmo1990_sol.pdf)
[Solutions from www.vnmath.com, page 7](http://estoyanov.net/files/MATAMATIKA/aziatsko_tihookeanski_matholimpiadi.pdf)

Comment: Do the solutions to the original math olympiad problem involve explicit constructions or is there an abstract argument that such a hexagon and tiling must exist?

Comment: After a little googling, I found two solutions that involve explicit constructions, and quite different from mine tbh

Comment: @CristianBaeza: Please edit your question to at least include links to the solutions you found. (Summarizing the constructions would be ideal.) This will help people avoid both duplicating the effort in those constructions and your effort in searching the web.

Answer (score 1):

Take triangles with sides $1$, $3$, and $3$. Line up five of them to form a trapezoid with sides $2$, $3$, $3$, and $3$. Put the sixth one flush on the side of the trapezoid opposite the length $2$ side, and the seventh one flush on the other length $3$ side of the sixth one.

Comment: At first I put the seventh one the wrong way around and only got a pentagon.